# connect 4 (4-in-a-row) , place a mark on the board, c program

Tags: c

I made a connect 4 game where the player can choose the number of rows and columns.
this is my function to put the player's mark on the board:

```
void get_and_check_place_on_the_board (char player_sign, char board[][25], int columns_number, int rows_number, int place_on_board)
{
    int column_chosen;
    while (place_on_board[0] == -1)
    {
    do {
        printf(game_messages[MSG_GET_COLUMN]);
        scanf("%d", &column_chosen);
       } while (column_chosen <= 0 && column_chosen > columns_number);

    for (int i = rows_number - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (board[i][column_chosen - 1] == ' ')
        {
            board[i][column_chosen - 1] = player_sign;
            place_on_board[0] = i;
            place_on_board[1] = column_chosen - 1;
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("column full");
    }
}
```

player_sign is "R" or "Y", the player decide the rows and columns number (not more than 25), and the place_on_board is an array, initialized to {-1, -1}.
The compiler says that: "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector", and that: "parameter 'place_on_board' set but not used"

what can i do?

Comment: What line of code has the error?

Comment: `place_on_board` is a single `int`. So `place_on_board[0]` is an error.

Comment: If `place_on_board` is an array, then pass it as `int *place_on_board`.